# Merging dataframes returns nan column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes (A and B) which have the following types.

A:

```
  ID                             int64
  Marges                        object
  RegioS                        object
  Period                        object
```

B:

```
 RegioS     object
 Name       object
```

Dataframe A  looks like this:

```
ID     Marges    RegioS     Period
200    AA        GM21       2019-11
204    AB        GM33       2019-09
202    AC        GM44       2019-06
```

and dataframe B looks like:

```
RegioS     Name
GM21       NL
GM33       DE
GM44       US
```

Now, I try to merge the dataframes using: `df_results = df_A.merge(df_B, how='left', on='RegioS')`. However, the `name` column only contains `nan` values. I want `df_result to look like:

```
ID     Marges    RegioS     Period      Name
200    AA        GM21       2019-11     NL
204    AB        GM33       2019-09     DE
202    AC        GM44       2019-06     US
```

`Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Give some examples how the dataframes look like and what the desired output is

Comment: @drops I added some more explanation

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any errors in your code, it gives the expected output. This may in your input dataset problem. My implementation you can find [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VDESdgNeUGCUwtPAii8CiB6LUR7GSsGS?usp=sharing).

[image]